# Full screen image in a metro windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

i am developing a Windows 8 "Metro" App. In this App I want to put an Image as a wallpaper.
The Image is 1600x900 Pixels big. Now, when i try a bigger Screen in the Simulator the Image
is not scaled to fill the whole Screen. How can i achieve this? I tried to follow the Microsoft 
Guidelines for different Screen sizes, like for example putting the Image in a canvas, but it doesnt
work. Can someone help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: It is XAML, sorry i forgot to mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly what you have tried, or which guidelines your were looking at. But you can always add an `ImageBrush` to your Grid like this.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/img101.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <TextBlock Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Hello World" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="60" ></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: @BasemAbdelfattah Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

In one of my apps, I use a full-screen image as a background watermark, by using the following CSS:

```
.watermark {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 140%;
    opacity: 0.05;
}
```

then, in the markup, I simply add an image tag, with the watermark class:

```
<img class="watermark" src="#" />
```

In my case, I'm setting the image source dynamically in the page's JS file, like so:

```
element.querySelector(".watermark").src = item.maptileUrl;
```

the above line grabs the URL for the image (a map tile) from the selected item that was passed to the page.

I tested my app in the simulator, and it works regardless of the screen size and resolution.

Be aware that depending on what your image is, using a width/height of 100% could result in your image being stretched vertically or horizontally.

Another possibly easier solution is to simply set the background-image style of the body tag to the desired image. You can read more about this property at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp (along with the background-repeat, background-size, etc.).

Comment: Thank you very much...i will try something similar, my Problem is that i am writing in XAML

Comment: Ah. Important piece of info, that. :-) Glad to see someone got you the answer, though.